# Get position with jQuery offset() of element giving incorrect numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a Cordova app which uses a live camera preview and I need the position (relative to the entire page) to place that preview. I have played with jQuery offset, position, and a slew of other posts' suggestions to no avail.

```
var position = $("#liveCamera").offset();
```

or

```
   $("#liveCamera").html(position.top);
   $("#liveCamera").html(position.left);
```

I'me expecting something in the neighborhood of {top: 250, left: 300}, but I'm getting {top: 50, left: 1313.806884765625} no matter what I try! What's truly odd is that left of 1313 is actually off of the screen...

**Other stuff I've tried**

Per other suggestions I tried to look at scroll positions but both are equal to 0.

```
$(document).scrollTop()   // = 0
$(document).scrollLeft()  // = 0
```

If I try to use `$("#liveCamera").position()` instead of offset() then I get {top: 1, left: 0}, which is obviously incorrect

I saw another post suggesting adding up the parents' offsets as the below code, but the results are just as bad:

```
console.log($("#liveCamera").offset());
console.log($("#liveCamera").parent().offset());
console.log($("#liveCamera").parent().parent().offset());
console.log($("#liveCamera").parent().parent().parent().offset());
console.log($("#liveCamera").parent().parent().parent().parent().offset());
```

Which results in

> {top: 50, left: 1313.806884765625}
>
> {top: 50, left: 1313.806884765625}
>
> {top: 0, left: 1013.760009765625}
>
> {top: 0, left: 1013.760009765625}
>
> {top: -1, left: 1013.760009765625}

1) How can I get the true position of an element relative to the entire page?

**Update**

Still no luck and I have tried everything I can think of. I am thinking that due to the depth of where this element is located it's awkward to find its location; but I don't understand how it can be so difficult to find an element's true position on the page! I don't mind using extra libraries or any way to get the job done.

I am using AngularJS and Ionic Framework, so the element in question is located in a template view a few levels deep into the app.

Comment: What's the CSS position attribute? static, relative or absolute?

Comment: jQuery internally uses [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) if it is available. I would guess that the result is correct, but maybe you use some kind of layout/container that makes it _look wrong_, because it e.g. hides the scrollbar of the window and maybe using 2d transformations.

Comment: @frenchie, it and all of it's parents are relative

Comment: @t.niese I tried writting my own js using getboundingClientRect and got the exact same results. There's no way it's correct at 50x1313 ... the element in question is roughly equidistant from the top and left of the screen, at about 25% screen height and width

Comment: I don't know which WebKit Version Cordova is using on your test environment neither your layout, so it is impossible to tell you why it happens. Either it is a bug of the WebKit version that is used, or the values are correct. To get the origin of the problem I would loop from the element through all parents up to the document, until the `left` is not `1013` anymore  and then check what the style values of element and the last one that has the position `1013` are (especially for `transformation`, `position` and `overflow`), I would still guess the problem is something like  `transformation`.

Comment: Thane @t.niese I'll try that... but the platform is a bit irrelevant since I get exactly* the same numbers when running it in a browser (Chrome) as when I deploy it to my device.